# Set-Cookie not working after migrating from ASP.net Core 2.2 to 3.0 (CORS enabled)

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-3.0

I migrate my project from ASP.net Core 2.2 to 3.0.

After successful migration I saw that my login is not working. Note: I am calling API from another origin.

I set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:webisite.com` header but I don't know why although I sent these headers and `Set-Cookie` header, cookie doesn't set in the browser for next requests.

[image: Response]

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Could you show your startup Configure method?Do you configure it like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-startupconfigure

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There is breaking change when migrating from 2.2 to 3.0:

[HTTP: Some cookie SameSite defaults changed to None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0#http-some-cookie-samesite-defaults-changed-to-none)

I changed my append cookie code to this and the problem solved.

```
Response.Cookies.Append(AuthCookieKey, loginTicket, new CookieOptions()
{
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax
});
```